# Regular Expression for SOAP Response in Groovy

Tags: regex, soap, groovy

Did I do something wrong here on matching/extracting the value of UserToken (ie. "bb14MY") using Regular Expression in Groovy??

```
@Grab(group='com.github.groovy-wslite', module='groovy-wslite', version='1.1.0')
import wslite.soap.*
import wslite.http.auth.*
import java.util.regex.*      
import groovy.xml.*
import groovy.util.*
import java.lang.*

...
...
...

def soapResponse = connection.content.text;

String str = println "$soapResponse";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\s*UserToken=&quot;(.*?)&quot;", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
if (matcher.find()) {
          println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

The output of $soapResponse looks like below.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    ContactAddress_Key=&quot;&quot; ImageFile=&quot;&quot; LocaleCode=&quot;en_US_EST&quot;
    UserToken=&quot;bb14MY&quot;
</loginReturn></p561:loginResponse></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: do you want to match bb14my?

Comment: Yes JILLI Aman. I were trying the match the UserToken value which is "bb14MY" in this SOAP request. I changes on each request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def soapResponse = connection.content.text;

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(/(?s)UserToken=&quot;(.*?)&quot;/, Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(soapResponse);
if (matcher.find()) {
          println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

This is what I did to solve my question.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following pattern to get your usertoken. I'm using a capturing group to get it.

```
UserToken=.+;(\w+).+;
```

### Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/pM9pE8/1).

Needless to say, your regex object must handle multilines.

Answer (score 0):

Using `^` here is wrong, as DOTALL just makes the linebreak match for a regular char.  I think you want MULTILINE, but it also just works without it.  E.g.

```
def soap="""\
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    ContactAddress_Key=&quot;&quot; ImageFile=&quot;&quot; LocaleCode=&quot;en_US_EST&quot;
    UserToken=&quot;bb14MY&quot;
</loginReturn></p561:loginResponse></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>"""
def pattern
def matcher

// stick with `Pattern.DOTALL` (`(?s)`), but get rid of handling for the start of the line:
pattern = /(?s)UserToken=&quot;(.*?)&quot;/
matcher = soap =~ pattern
assert matcher
assert matcher.group(1)=="bb14MY"

// or use `Pattern.MULTILINE` (`(?m)`) with your `^\s*`:
pattern = /(?m)^\s*UserToken=&quot;(.*?)&quot;/
matcher = soap =~ pattern
assert matcher
assert matcher.group(1)=="bb14MY"
```

Comment: The UserToken values keeps changing on each soap request.

Comment: @shaa0601 the assert is to show, that it works. matcher.group(1) contains the expected key for this input.  or maybe i dont get your point?